# Run a bash script from another user with Django

Tags: django, bash, shell, sudo

this is my first Django project, I apologies if I say some nonsense

To start a game server, I have to login with ssh as the user running the server, then type`./server start` to start it.

I want to be able to run this command from a webapp.
As of now, I've managed to do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNXxZ.png) on Django.

What I want to do is that when I press the "Start" button, this commands run on the server side:

```
su - gameuser -c '/home/gameuser/server start' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to login as the gameuser since I'm not a running the webapp as a sudo user.

How can I approach this problem?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

1. You can configure ssh keys for webapp user to login as gameuser without entering password and execute:
   ssh gameuser@localhost -c '/home/gameuser/server start' > /dev/null 2>&1
2. You can configure webuser to execute specified command with sudo (sudoers file is pretty flexible)
   add the following to /etc/sudoers
   webapp ALL = (gameuser) ALL
   and then you can run the following as webapp user
   sudo su - gameuser -c '/home/gameuser/server start' > /dev/null 2>&1
3. You can improve the second option, allowing webapp user to execute only specific command as gameuser, for example write start script ( /home/gameuser/server_start.sh ) and add to the /etc/sudoers:

webapp ALL = (gameuser) /home/gameuser/server_start.sh
and again you will able to run the following in more secure way.
sudo su -gameuser -c /home/gameuser/server_start.sh

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into this. However, this is not a "scalable" solution right? Since I have to manually had the config for each gameuser. Is there a way to go around this? Even if it requires to rebuild the webapp...

Comment: You can configure ssh keys for many users, the same is for sudo.
You can even use something like Jenkins or other popular CI/DI tool instead of your webapp.